# Use purrr on a position of element in nested list?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

**Situation:** I have a nested list in the image below. I want to use purrr to iterate over the second element of each nested list and apply a date conversion function.

[image: nested list]

**Problem:**  I can write a for loop easily to iterate over it but I want to use this with purrr. My nested list attempts have not worked out. Normal list fine, nested by position, not fine.

Reproducible example code from Maurits Evers (Thank you!)

```
lst <- list(
    list("one", "12345", "2019-01-01"),
    list("two", "67890", "2019-01-02"))
```

Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: Please use a reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . Images are unhelpful as anyone wanting to answer your query has to type out a structure to test code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the comment above to understand how to provide a reproducible example including sample data.

Since you don't provide sample data, let's create some minimal mock data similar to what is shown in your screenshot.

```
lst <- list(
    list("one", "12345", "2019-01-01"),
    list("two", "67890", "2019-01-02"))
```

To cast the third element of every `list` element `as.Date` we can then do

```
lst <- map(lst, ~{.x[[3]] <- as.Date(.x[[3]]); .x})
```

We can confirm that the third element of every `list` element is an object of type `Date`

```
str(lst)
#List of 2
# $ :List of 3
#  ..$ : chr "one"
#  ..$ : chr "12345"
#  ..$ : Date[1:1], format: "2019-01-01"
# $ :List of 3
#  ..$ : chr "two"
#  ..$ : chr "67890"
#  ..$ : Date[1:1], format: "2019-01-02"
```

---

### Update

A more `purrr`/`tidyverse`-canonical approach would be to use `modify_at` (thanks @H1)

```
lst <- map(lst, ~modify_at(.x, 3, as.Date))
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: `modify_at` works well here - `map(lst, ~modify_at(.x, 3, as.Date))`.

Comment: @H1 Ah yes, I just came across that as well:-) nice

Comment: @H1 - that's the one!

Comment: A `plyr` version: `plyr::llply(lst,function(x) {x[[3]]<- as.Date(x[[3]]);x})`

Comment: Thanks Maurita and H1. I will read up on the functionality behind the pieces posted to understand more.