# modify particular element of nested list with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I'd like to modify each element of a nested list. But only a specific sub-element. In the example below, I'm aiming to modify the elements named "data".

```
# dummy data
mylist <- list(
  item1 = list(label = "My first label", data = 1:10),
  item2 = list(label = "My second label", data = 10:20)
)
```

I can achieve this using `modify_in()` nested within `map()`, as below. (E.g. from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121113/use-purrr-on-a-position-of-element-in-nested-list)).

```
library(purrr)

map(mylist, \(l) modify_in(l, "data", \(dat) {append(dat, 99)})) # using `append` as an example
```

But I'm wondering whether there's a simpler approach, perhaps using any of `purrr`'s other functions? My actual use-case is more complex and I'd like to avoid nested iterations if possible.

Something like this (which doesn't work) would be ideal

```
modify_in(mylist, list(seq_along(mylist), "data"), \(dat) append(dat, 99)) # doesn't work
```

Looking at the documentation of the other `purrr` functions (e.g. `modify_depth()`) has not given me any answers, hence turning to you good folk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `modify` to loop over each list element `l` (in your case  `item1` etc.) and check if it has a sub-element `l[["data]]`, and in this case, use `append`.

A nested loop is not necessary, but it is important to `return` the whole list element after changing the `data` sub-element.

```r
library(purrr)

mylist <- list(
  item1 = list(label = "My first label", data = 1:10),
  item2 = list(label = "My second label", data = 10:20)
)

modify(mylist,
       .f = \(l) {
         if(!is.null(l[["data"]])) {
           l[["data"]] <- append(l[["data"]], 99)   
         }
         return(l)
         }
       )
#> $item1
#> $item1$label
#> [1] "My first label"
#> 
#> $item1$data
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 99
#> 
#> 
#> $item2
#> $item2$label
#> [1] "My second label"
#> 
#> $item2$data
#>  [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 99
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rrapply` replacing each element satisfying the condition or class using argument f.

```
library(rrapply)

# append 99 to elements named data
rrapply(mylist, 
  condition = \(x, .xname) .xname == "data",
  f = \(x) append(x, 99),
  how = "replace"
)
    
# append 99 to numeric elements
rrapply(mylist, 
  classes = "numeric",
  f = \(x) append(x, 99),
  how = "replace"
)

# append 99 to position 2 elements
rrapply(mylist, 
  condition = \(x, .xpos) tail(.xpos, 1) == 2,
  f = \(x) append(x, 99),
  how = "replace"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R alternative :

```
lapply(mylist, \(x) {x$data <- c(x$data, 99);x})

#$item1
#$item1$label
#[1] "My first label"

#$item1$data
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 99


#$item2
#$item2$label
#[1] "My second label"

#$item2$data
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 99
```